# Why this while cicle doesn't restart?

Tags: python, while-loop

It is supposed to reassign the value of termsv2 at the end when the second while finshed and it should start again, but nothing happens.

```
def nPrints(nTerms):
    print(terms[x])
    terms.pop(x)

import random
terms = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
nTerms=int(input("Tell me the number of terms you want to be displayed: "))
Again = True
while nTerms>len(terms):
    print("Too big number")
    nTerms=int(input("A smaller number please: "))
while Again == True:
    termsv2 = terms
    while len(termsv2) != 0:
        if len(termsv2) >= nTerms:
            for a in range(0,nTerms):
                x = random.randint(0, len(termsv2)-1)
                nPrints(x)
            input("press any key")
            print("----------------------------")
        else:
            for b in range(0,len(termsv2)):
                x = random.randint(0, len(termsv2)-1)
                nPrints(x)

    re = input("Restart?: ")
    if re == "y":
        termsv2 = terms
    else:
        Again=False
        
print("----------------------------")
print("Finish")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an alias on line 13 which means any change applied to the list `termesv2` is also applied to `terms`as they both represent the same memory sectors. When you finish the first loop the list (which has two names) the list is empty and the statement `len(termsv2) != 0` is alwais false.

What you want to do on this line 13  and on line 28 is:

```py
termsv2 = terms[:]
```

Which creates a copy of the list (and not an alias). Indeed, the command `my_list[i:j]` returns a **fresh** list containing the elements of `my_list` from index i to j-1. If i is not specified it starts from 0 and if j is not specified it goes to the end of the list.